# Edit Already Saved Notes from this ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm Building this note app with react js and i have the `AddNote` component to add new notes to the `notes` state in app.js, but I want to be able to edit the already saved notes by an `input` tag and `textarea` when the `FaExpanAlt` icon from the `Note` component is clicked

```js
//APP.JS Component
const notesElements = props.notes.map((note) => {
  return (
    <Note 
      id = {note.id} 
      title = {note.title}
      bodyText = {note.bodyText}
      date = {note.date}
      color = {note.bgColor}
      delete ={props.delete}
    />
  )
})
const [noteText, setNoteText] = React.useState('')
const [title, setTitle] = React.useState('')
const [notes, setnotes] = React.useState([
  {
    id : nanoid(), 
    title:'Heading 1',
    bodyText:'Sample text',
    date: '1/08/2022', 
    bgColor: 'pink'
  },
  {
    id : nanoid(), 
    title:'Heading 1',
    bodyText:'Sample text',
    date: '1/08/2022',
    bgColor: 'yellow'
  } ,
  {
    id : nanoid(), 
    title:'Heading 1',
    bodyText:'Sample text',
    date: '1/08/2022',
    bgColor: 'yellow'
  } 
])

return (
  textAreaFlag ?

  <AddNote 
    textAreaFlag ={NewNotesArea}
    setNote ={setNote}
    title ={title}
    bodyText ={bodyText}
    setTitle ={setTitle}
    setNoteText ={setNoteText} 
  /> :
  <div style={{backgroundColor: darkMode && "#343434" }} className='app'>
    <Header 
    search = {setSearchText}
    searchText = {searchText}
    darkMode = {DarkModeToggle}
    darkValue = {darkMode}/>

    <div className="note-list">
      {notesElements}
    </div>

    <button 
      className='add-button'
      onClick={NewNotesArea}
    >+</button>
  </div> 
)
```

```js
//AddNote.js component

export default function  AddNote(props) {


  function handleChange (event){
    console.log(event.target.value)
    setNoteText(event.target.value);
  }

  function handletitlechange (event){
    console.log(event.target.value)
    setTitle(event.target.value)
  }


  function handleSaveClick (){
    props.setNote(title,noteText, color)
    props.textAreaFlag()
  }
    
  return (
    <div className=' add-note' style={{backgroundColor: props.color}}>
      <div className='add-note-top'> 
        <button onClick={props.textAreaFlag}> <FaAngleLeft /> 
        </button>
          
        <input 
          type="color" 
          value={props.color} 
          onChange={e => {
            console.log(color)
            setColor(e.target.value)
          }} 
        />    
      </div>
      <div className='addnote-inputs'>
        <input 
          placeholder='Title'
          value = {props.title}
          onChange = {handletitlechange}
        />
        <textarea
          cols='50'
          rows='50'
          placeholder='Type to add a note...'
          value={props.noteText}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
        </textarea>
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={handleSaveClick} 
        className='save'>Save
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```js
//Note.js Component
function Note (props){
  return (
    <div className='note' style= {{backgroundColor: props.color}}>
      <div className='inner-note'>
        <h4>{props.title}</h4>
        <span>{props.bodyText.slice(0, 150)}</span>
        <div className='note-footer'>
          <p>{props.date}</p>
          <FaTrash 
            onClick={() => props.delete(props.id)}
            className = "delete-icon"
          />
          <FaExpandAlt />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why should it edit a note when it clearly says `delete`?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Check the code, the button that says delete is above the `FaExpandAlt` button that will edit the note

Comment: Ok sorry, the `FaExpandAlt ` do nothing. What have you tried already?